# Number of real roots of $f(x)=^5−5−4$

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=^5+^4−^4-^3+^3+^2−^2-x-4−4$ is the expanded form of the equation $f(x)=^5−5−4$
which simplifies to  $f(x)=(x+1)(^4−^3+^2-x-4)$
The equation $f(x)=^5−5−4$ when entered in desmos.com shows that it has two real roots. How do we conclude that equation $f(x)=^5−5−4$ has two real roots.I am not able to find another root.

Comment: Well, I'd have said that it had $3$ real roots, as $x=-1$ is a double root.  You can factor out $(x+1)^2$ if you like or note that $f'(x)=0\implies x=\pm 1$ and work from there.

Comment: The equation intersect y-axis at 2 point please check the equation by entering it in desmos.com, one point is (-1,0) and other point is (1.651,0)

Comment: As I say, $x=-1$ is a double root.  Thus $(x+1)^2\,|\,f(x)$ or, equivalently, both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ vanish at $x=-1$.  Counting roots with multiplicity is standard...it has the nice feature that, using that way of counting, every polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ complex roots.  That statement is false if you ignore multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Descartes' Rule of Signs](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/drofsign.htm):

$f(x)=+x^5-5x-4$ has one sign change, so it has one positive root.

$f(-x)=(-x)^5-5(-x)-4 = -x^5+5x-4$ has one sign change, so it has one negative root.

Putting it all together, the function has **two** real roots.

Comment: Thank You for your prompt reply, is there any other way of finding number of roots. I remember that if f'(x) has no roots then f(x) has one roots and so

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi By luck, this function has a double root at $x=-1$, so you are left with a cubic. You can calculate the [cubic discriminant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cubic-discriminant/), and the sign will tell you how many real roots there are.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=x^5-5x-4$$
$$f'(x)=5x^4-5$$

In the real domain, the first derivative cancels at $x=\pm 1$. But $f(-1)=0$ means that $x=-1$ is a double root. The second derivative test shows that $x=-1$ is a local maximum and $x=1$ a local minimum. On the other hand, $f(0)=-4$, $f(1)=-8$ and $f(2)=18$. Since the second derivative changes sign only at $x=0$, there is another root between $x=1$ and $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^5-5x-4$, and $f'(x)=0$ has solutions $x=\pm 1$. $f''(-1)<0$ and $f''(1)>0$, and so this means that $f$ has two extreme points, which again means that $f$ touches the $x$-axis $\color{purple}1$ , $\color{blue}2$ or $\color{red}3$ times.

Since $f(-1)=0$ and $f(1)\neq 0$ $f$ must cross the $x$-axis 2 times.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you have proven, it is $ f(-1)=0 $ and therefore $ x=-1 $ is a root of the polynomial. Now we can also see that $ f(1)f(2) < 0 $ with $ f(x) $ being continuous on the interval [1,2]. Therefore, from Bolzano's theorem we can say:

$$ \exists x_0 \in (1,2) \ | \  f(x_0)=0 $$

Consequently, we proved that there is another root.

We know that $ f(x) $ is also differentiable with $$ f'(x)=5x^4-5=5(x^4-1)=5(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1) $$ from where we can see that $ f'(-1)=f'(1)=0 $

Now is the fun part : Let's assume there is another root of $ f(x) $, say $ u \in \mathbb R $

It is true that $ f(u) = 0 $.
If $ u \in (x_0, +\infty) $ then from Rolle's theorem on the interval [$ x_0,u$], it holds that:
$$ \exists i \in (x_0,u) \ | \ f'(i)=0 $$
But it is also true that: $ x_0 \in (1,2) \Rightarrow x_0 > 1 \Rightarrow i>x_0>1$.

However both of the two roots of $f'(x)$ are located on $ x \le 1 $
So, if there can't be a root of $f(x)$ on [$x_0, +\infty$] (In other words u can't be on $ (x_0,+\infty)) $

You can easily apply the same technique on the intervals $ [-\infty, -1] $ and $ [-1,x_0]$ and find out that u can't be on either $ [-\infty, -1] $ and $ [-1,x_0]$ and therefore you are stuck with only two real roots.

*If you didn't understand something feel free to ask.*